# I use Angular 2 when I have done a function to see the details of a formation already added, nothing is displayed

Tags: node.js, angular

When I have done a function to see the details of a formation already added, nothing is displayed.

***Error***

> *GET http://localhost:3001/formations/undefined 0 ()*
>
> *EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null*
>
> *Subscriber.js:246 Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}*

**This is my show.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" >
  <div class="panel-heading">formation detail Form : You can see the detail information of an foration in this page of the EMS Apps.</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" *ngIf=forms>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="emp_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">formation's Full title : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <p class="form-control">{{forms.title}}</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="position" class="col-sm-2 control-label">formation url : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <p class="form-control">{{forms.url}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="department" class="col-sm-2 control-label">formation description : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <p class="form-control">{{forms.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

  </div>
</div>
```

**this is my show.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormationService } from '../../services/formation.service';
import { Formation } from '../../../app/formation';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.css']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    public formationService:FormationService,
    public route:ActivatedRoute,
    public router:Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFormation();
  }

  formation:Formation;
  getFormation(){
    var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.formationService.getFormation(id)
        .subscribe(formation=>{
          this.formation = formation;
        })
  }

}
```

**this is my home.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Title</b></td>
      <td><b>url</b></td>
      <td><b>description</b></td>
      <td width="275" align="center"><b>Action</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
     <tr *ngFor="let forms of formation  | async " >
        <td>{{forms.title}}</td>
        <td>{{forms.url}}</td> 
        <td>{{forms.description}}</td>
        <td width="275"> 
            <a class="btn btn-info" routerLink="/show/{{forms._id}}">Detail</a> 
            <a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="/edit/{{forms._id}}" >Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteFormation(forms._id)" >Delete</a>
        </td>
        </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: this is what diplayed]

*this is my service file*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 


@Injectable()
export class FormationService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getFormations(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3001/formations")
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
  addFormation(info){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3001/formations",info)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
  getFormation(id){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3001/formations/"+id)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
  deleteFormation(id){
    return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3001/formations/"+id)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
  updateFormation(id, info){
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:3001/formations/"+id,info)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share share your 'formationService' file?

Comment: Please add your service class. And why are you calling `http://localhost:3001/formations/undefined`? There is no `id` in the url, so maybe call the service only if `id` is specified

Comment: @Rotemya I added my service file

Comment: @David I added my service file

Comment: i think it's a router problem, as i mentioned in my answer, try to subscribe to the router instead of getting from snapshot !

Comment: Just checking, is your API `http://localhost:3001/formations/<id>` still running? (You cann acces it in the browser). Maybe you crashed it when you send undefined as the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't realy get you problem, but from what i see, you should
instead of

```
var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

try to subscribe to the router using queryParams

```
this.formation = this.route.queryParams.pipe(map(params => {
      this.id = params.id;
      return this.formationService.getFormation(id)
})
```

in your html

```
<tbody *ngIf="formation | async as formation">
 <tr *ngFor="let forms of formation">

 </tr>
</tbody >
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you send http request without id.

Just add a condition on the id:

```js
  getFormation(){
    var id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    if(id){
        this.formationService.getFormation(id)
            .subscribe(formation=>{
          this.formation = formation;
        })
    }

  }
```

And it will be a good practice to add this check also in the service layer before sending request with 'id' as a  a query param.